# Will LibreOffice 3.4 be included in an update?

Tags: 11.04, libreoffice

Ubuntu 11.04 ships with LibreOffice 3.3.2

In a few weeks LibreOffice will publish a new Version LibreOffice 3.4

Will Ubuntu release this update like a new Version of Firefox? (a few days after the release)

Or: similar to openoffice? (more or less never)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LibreOffice 3.4.3 for Natty was released 7 Oct 2011.  Consider adding the libreoffice repository:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will make sure you're always up to date with the newest versions of Libreoffice.

Comment: But why won't the Ubuntu repos be updated?

Comment: As stated by Terry, Ubuntu does not release new versions in the official repos until they have been adequately tested, which is often not until the next major release of Ubuntu. This is to make sure that all packages you download from the official repositories are stable, and work well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I note (at the time of writing this) that libreoffice in oneiric is version 3.4 for Oneiric.

Reading the [oneiric blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-libreoffice-packaging) - the libreoffice will be updated for lucid/maverick/natty when oneiric has been successfully tested/built.  This will either be through the PPA or through the standard backports repository.

EDIT (10/10/11): the PPA has now been updated with v3.4.3 - backports has yet to be upgraded

Whilst we wait - see this [AU Question as a guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46826/how-to-install-libreoffice-3-4-final-in-ubuntu-11-04-or-10-10) on how to update to the latest version of Libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

No, the "ppa:libreoffice/ppa" repository does not contain the 3.4 version, only the 3.3 version.  And when I tried adding the 3.4.2 version from the ODF site, it didn't create the menu entries for Gnome (Mint 11, based on Natty/11.04)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 - Oneiric Ocelot, that is in RC and will be release in few days, includes LibreOffice 3.4.3.

If someone is interested, this is the link to feature improvements in LibreOffice 3.4:

http://www.libreoffice.org/download/3-4-new-features-and-fixes/

Answer (score -1):

for new versions of software you will properly have to wait for the next release, this is what normally happens.

if a ppa gets released for the software then you can install this and get the latest versions.