# How do i install Libreoffice 3.4?

Tags: 11.04, installation, ppa, libreoffice

I read that it has better GTK+ integration,is faster and java has been minimized . so i wanted to try it .
How do i install it ?
A PPA would be preferable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LibreOffice 3.4.3 for Natty was released 7 Oct 2011.

The standard [LibreOffice ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16695/is-there-a-libreoffice-ppa) should be used to update - see linked question on how to install.

For those that like to live on the bleeding edge, there are .deb files you can download directly from the LibreOffice website [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/pre-releases/).  Obviously, these will be vanilla LibreOffice and therefore probably will not include any stuff the ubuntu packagers also add.

---

Linked Question:

1. [Will LibreOffice 3.4 be included in an update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38026/will-libreoffice-3-4-be-included-in-an-update)

Answer (score 1):

Visit the PPA's overview page in Launchpad. click this link https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa

Step 2: Use the Display sources.list entries drop-down box to select the version of Ubuntu you're using.

Step 3: You'll see that the text-box directly below reads something like this:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main

Copy those lines.

Step 4: Open a terminal and type:

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

This will open a text editor containing the list of archives that your system is currently using. Scroll to the bottom of the file and paste the lines you copied in the step above.

Save the file and exit the text editor.

Step 5: Back on the PPA's overview page, look for the Signing key heading. You'll see something like:

1024R/72D340A3

Copy the portion after the slash but not including the help link; e.g. just 72D340A3.

Step 6: Now you need to add that key to your system so Ubuntu can verify the packages from the PPA. In your terminal, enter:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 72D340A3

Replace 72D340A3 with whatever you copied in the step 5.

This will now pull down the PPA's key and add it to your system.

Step 7: Now, as a one-off, you should tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about, including the PPA you just added:

sudo aptitude update

sudo aptitude install libreoffice

Now you're ready to start libreoffice

Comment: the ppa does not have 3.4 :(

Comment: The repository can be enabled with one command which takes care of the signing key too: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

Comment: The v.3.4 has just become stable today. It will be added to the PPA soon (that PPa is for stable releases, so betas won't be added to it).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instructions --you have to download DEB packages until they update the official PPA.

http://www.unixmen.com/software/1755-libreoffice-340-is-released-installation-instructions-for-ubuntu-fedora-debian