# How to install LibreOffice 3.4 Final In Ubuntu 11.04 or 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, libreoffice

How do I install the final version of LibreOffice 3.4 in Ubuntu 10.10, 11.04 and the latest version of 11.10

Comment: There is a DEB file at their download page under "Other way to download LibreOffice". I'm almost tempted to downlad/install it but I'll wait for a PPA.

Comment: I was thinking more in the lines of a PPA so if an update comes out I will get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note** Remove the previous version of OpenOffice or LibreOffice with this command

**For OpenOffice**

```
sudo apt-get remove openoffice*.*
```

**For LibreOffice**

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice*.*
```

1 - Go to; [LibreOffice 3.4 Download](http://www.libreoffice.org/download)

2 - Select **Linux x86** deb or **x64 deb** depending on your computer

3 - Save & extract the file to ~/Desktop

4 - Rename the file as libreoffice

5 - Enter the following command into terminal and wait for the process to finish.

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/libreoffice/DEBS/*.deb
```

6 - Run the following command to finish the installation:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/libreoffice/DEBS/desktop-integration/libreoffice3.4-debian-menus_3.4-12_all.deb
```

You now have Libreoffice 3.4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-install-libreoffice-34-in-ubuntu.html
I installed manually as:
(for 11.04 but i think it would be appropriate for 10.10 or 10.04)

- `sudo apt-get purge libreoffice libreoffice-core` (purge 3.2 version if you have 11.04)
- download 3.4 debs from here: http://www.libreoffice.org/download/
- unarchive all debs to one folder (fore example **~/debs/libreoffice**)
- `sudo dpkg -iR ~/debs/libreoffice/*.deb`
- `libreoffice3.4`