# How to upgrade LibreOffice to 3.4.2

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, libreoffice

How to upgrade LibreOffice from 3.3.2 to 3.4.2 Final (2011-08-01) on 10.10

I added the PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

and tried to  use `update manager` in `system -> administration` to upgrade it and could not find any package to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libreoffice team have not updated their PPA with any newer version of libreoffice beyond 3.3.2 for maverick and natty.  I note (at the time of writing this) they have attempted to produce a build of 3.4.1 for Oneiric.

Reading the [oneiric blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-libreoffice-packaging) - the libreoffice will be updated for lucid/maverick/natty when oneiric has been successfully tested/built.  This will either be through the PPA or through the standard backports repository.

Whilst we wait - see this [AU Question as a guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46826/how-to-install-libreoffice-3-4-final-in-ubuntu-11-04-or-10-10) on how to update to the latest version of Libreoffice.

Comment: That is probable. But I got confused with statement in http://www.libreoffice.org/download/ "As a general rule, you are recommended to install LibreOffice via the installation methods recommended by your particular Linux distribution (such as the Ubuntu Software Center, in the case of Ubuntu Linux).This is because it is usually the simplest way to obtain an installation that is optimally integrated into your system. Indeed, LibreOffice may well be already installed by default when you originally install your Linux operating system."

Comment: I agree with the libreoffice statement.  Personally I would wait until the PPA is updated with stuff that has been specifically tested against lucid/maverick and natty.  Then again - some people like to "live on the edge" and hence install the very-very latest software.

Comment: The note on how to update to the latest version of Libreoffice will help me to get around the PPA problem. Thanks fossfreedom.

Comment: I tested new Gentoo 11.2 live DVD version. It has LibreOffice 3.4.2. So it depends on maintainers of particular OS distro.

Answer (score 1):

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ppa) will upgrade ubuntu 10.4 LTS to Libreoffice 3.4.